# Java - How to reprompt the user if the input is not an integer

Tags: java

I want to re prompt(noofcases) the user if the entered value is not an integer. I'm newer to java. kindly suggest me the best possible ways that i can re prompt(noofcases) the user to enter the integer value again till the user enters an integer value.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    fetchinput();
}
public static void fetchinput()
{
    int noofcases = 0;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    noofcases=input.nextInt();
    ArrayList<String> StringA = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> StringB = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<noofcases;i++)
    {
        StringA.add(input.next());
        StringB.add(input.next());
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println(StringA);
    System.out.println(StringB);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert your input string with Integer.parse() in a try{}catch(NumberformatException e) and print to System out when the exception occurs for a new input request. The rest is to read the same input stream again. You can do it in a while loop if you want or count the fails in a variable to abort.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I tend to use:

```
public int getNextInt(String promptMessage) {
    Integer ret; //We use Integer so it can be null
    do {
        System.out.println(promptMessage);
        String str = in.nextLine(); //nextLine is cleaner and doesn't get caught on newline characters
        try {
            ret = Integer.parseInt(str);
        catch(NumberFormatException e) { //Invalid
            System.out.println("Input an integer."); 
        }
    } while(ret==null); //Loop while invalid
    return ret; //Return result, unboxed
}
```